# How can I implement a spoiler quote with just CSS?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a `blockquote` like this:

```
<blockquote class="spoiler">Soopah sekkrit!</blockquote>
```

I want to make it hidden, only showing it if the user hovers over it. I'm doing it now with JS:

```
blockquote.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    this.style.height = this.offsetHeight + 'px';
    this.dataset.contents = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = '';
});
blockquote.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    this.style.height = '';
    this.innerHTML = this.dataset.contents;
});
```

Is there a better way to do this, with CSS?

It has to keep its `background-color`, size, and work for contents with custom colors. If possible, I'd also like to animate it so the contents fade in gradually.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with CSS. Essentially, you want to make all of the contents be invisible. In CSS, this means transparent.

First use the [hover pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover) inside the [not pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot):

```
.spoiler:not(:hover)
```

But we also need to select all the child elements of the hovered spoiler, to set their colors and backgrounds:

```
.spoiler:not(:hover) *
```

And we set both the color and background (only for the child elements) to `transparent` to make them invisible to the user. All together:

```css
.spoiler:not(:hover), .spoiler:not(:hover) * { color: transparent }
.spoiler:not(:hover) * { background: transparent }

code { padding: 2px; background: #bbb }
a { color: #00f }
```

```html
Hover: <blockquote class="spoiler">Some stuff <a>and a colored link</a> <code>and some code!</code></blockquote>
```

We can also add a [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to make it smoother:

```css
.spoiler { transition: color 0.5s } /* we have to put this outside the :hover to make it work fading both in and out */
.spoiler:not(:hover), .spoiler:not(:hover) * { color: transparent }
.spoiler * { transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s }
.spoiler:not(:hover) * { background: transparent }

code { padding: 2px; background: #bbb; color: #000 } /* add color to prevent double transition */
a { color: #00f }
```

```html
Hover: <blockquote class="spoiler">Some stuff <a>and a colored link</a> <code>and some code!</code></blockquote>
```

To make it obvious to the user that the blockquote is hoverable, you can add some text with the [`::after` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter) to be shown when the blockquote isn't hovered:

```css
.spoiler { transition: color 0.5s; position: relative } /* relative position for positioning the pseudo-element */
.spoiler:not(:hover), .spoiler:not(:hover) * { color: transparent }
.spoiler * { transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s }
.spoiler:not(:hover) * { background: transparent }
.spoiler::after {
    content: 'hover to view spoiler';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    color: transparent;
}
.spoiler:not(:hover)::after {
    color: #666;
    transition: color 0.3s 0.3s; /* delayed transition to keep the text from overlapping */
}

code { padding: 2px; background: #bbb; color: #000 }
a { color: #00f }
```

```html
<blockquote class="spoiler">
    Some stuff <a>and a colored link</a> <code>and some code!</code>
    <blockquote class="spoiler">Nesting bonus!</blockquote>
</blockquote>
```

For stuff like images, svgs (tho inline SVG can be very granularly controlled), canvases, and all that fancy stuff, instead of `color` you'd have to use [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity). We can make it work with these by adding this:

```
.spoiler img { transition: opacity 0.5s, background 0.5s }
.spoiler:not(:hover) img { opacity: 0 }
```

Answer (score 18):

Here's something very similar to what I use in [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch):

```css
.spoiler, .spoiler > * { transition: color 0.5s, opacity 0.5s }
.spoiler:not(:hover) { color: transparent }
.spoiler:not(:hover) > * { opacity: 0 }
/* fix weird transitions on Chrome: */
blockquote, blockquote > *:not(a) { color: black }
```

```css
.spoiler, .spoiler > * { transition: color 0.5s, opacity 0.5s }
.spoiler:not(:hover) { color: transparent }
.spoiler:not(:hover) > * { opacity: 0 }
/* fix weird transitions on Chrome: */
blockquote, blockquote > *:not(a) { color: black }

/* some basic bg styles for demonstration purposes */
blockquote { background: #fed; margin: 1em 0; padding: 8px; border-left: 2px solid #cba }
code { background: #ccc; padding: 2px }
img { vertical-align: middle }
```

```html
<blockquote class="spoiler">
  Soopah sekkrit text with <code>code</code> and <a href="#">links</a> and <img src="//sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png" width="100" /> images!
  <p>You can also have paragraphs in here.</p>
  <ul><li>And lists too!</li></ul>
  <blockquote class="spoiler">Even nested spoilers work!</blockquote>
</blockquote>
```

This is somewhat simpler than [your own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34259172), and works for arbitrary content including images and even nested spoilers!  (See demo snippet above.)

Alas, this method seems to suffer from weird transition effects on Chrome if any of the child elements of the spoiler have `color: inherit`.  (Basically, what's happening is that these elements will have *both* their text color set to transparent and their opacity set to 0.  Because opacities combine multiplicatively, the combined transition will thus appear slower — halfway through the fade-in, when the element itself is at 50% opacity, the *text* in it is at 50% × 50% = 25% opacity.)  I've added an extra CSS rule to the example above to fix this, but it does make things a bit complicated.

---

What I *actually* do in SOUP is slightly different.  I wrap the contents of each spoiler in an extra inner `<div>`, which lets me simplify the CSS further to just:

```css
.spoiler > div { opacity: 0; transition: opacity 0.5s }
.spoiler:hover > div { opacity: 1 }
```

```css
.spoiler > div { opacity: 0; transition: opacity 0.5s }
.spoiler:hover > div { opacity: 1 }

/* some basic bg styles for demonstration purposes */
blockquote { background: #fed; margin: 1em 0; padding: 8px; border-left: 2px solid #cba }
code { background: #ccc; padding: 2px }
img { vertical-align: middle }
```

```html
<blockquote class="spoiler"><div>
  Soopah sekkrit text with <code>code</code> and <a href="#">links</a> and <img src="//sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png" width="100" /> images!
  <p>You can also have paragraphs in here.</p>
  <ul><li>And lists too!</li></ul>
  <blockquote class="spoiler"><div>Even nested spoilers work!</div></blockquote>
<div></blockquote>
```

The main advantages of this method are simplicity and robustness: I don't have to use `:not()` selectors, improving compatibility with older browsers, and the `transition` styles can't conflict with other transitions possibly defined on the elements *inside* the spoiler.  This method also doesn't suffer from the color transition weirdness on Chrome described above, since it only uses opacity transitions.

Overall, this is the method I recommend.  The disadvantage, of course, is that you need to include the extra `<div>`s in your HTML.

---

**Ps.** Please consider also providing some way to make the spoilers permanently visible, especially for touch screen users who may find it very hard to "hover" the cursor over an element.  A simple solution is to use a JavaScript click event handler to toggle the `spoiler` class, e.g. like this (using jQuery):

```js
$('.spoiler').on( 'click', function (e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('spoiler');
  e.stopPropagation();
} );
```

```js
$('.spoiler').on( 'click', function (e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('spoiler');
  e.stopPropagation();
} );
```

```css
.spoiler > div { opacity: 0; transition: opacity 0.5s }
.spoiler:hover > div { opacity: 1 }

/* some basic bg styles for demonstration purposes */
blockquote { background: #fed; margin: 1em 0; padding: 8px; border-left: 2px solid #cba }
code { background: #ccc; padding: 2px }
img { vertical-align: middle }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<blockquote class="spoiler"><div>
  Soopah sekkrit text with <code>code</code> and <a href="#">links</a> and <img src="//sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png" width="100" /> images!
  <p>You can also have paragraphs in here.</p>
  <ul><li>And lists too!</li></ul>
  <blockquote class="spoiler"><div>Even <a href="//example.com">nested</a> spoilers work!</div></blockquote>
<div></blockquote>
```

or, if you'd prefer to use delegated event handling (so that you don't have to keep adding new click handlers every time you load new content that includes spoilers via Ajax):

```js
$(document).on( 'click', '.spoiler, .spoiler-off', function (e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('spoiler').toggleClass('spoiler-off');
  e.stopPropagation();
} );
```

```js
$(document).on( 'click', '.spoiler, .spoiler-off', function (e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('spoiler').toggleClass('spoiler-off');
  e.stopPropagation();
} );
```

```css
.spoiler > div { opacity: 0; transition: opacity 0.5s }
.spoiler:hover > div { opacity: 1 }

/* some basic bg styles for demonstration purposes */
blockquote { background: #fed; margin: 1em 0; padding: 8px; border-left: 2px solid #cba }
code { background: #ccc; padding: 2px }
img { vertical-align: middle }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<blockquote class="spoiler"><div>
  Soopah sekkrit text with <code>code</code> and <a href="#">links</a> and <img src="//sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png" width="100" /> images!
  <p>You can also have paragraphs in here.</p>
  <ul><li>And lists too!</li></ul>
  <blockquote class="spoiler"><div>Even <a href="//example.com">nested</a> spoilers work!</div></blockquote>
<div></blockquote>
```

(These should work with either of the CSS variants shown above.)

Comment: In your first example for the `<code>` I first see the background fade in, then the text after that instead of both at once.

Comment: @bjb568: Ah, I see the problem: the color transition combines weirdly with the opacity transition if any nested elements have `color: inherit`. For some reason, this doesn't happen on Firefox, which is why I didn't notice it initially, but it does happen on Chrome. I've edited the examples above to set `color: black` on `<code>` and `<blockquote>` elements, which should fix it. (Only the first example actually *needs* that edit, but I made it to all of them for consistency.)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a strategy that works pretty well, looks nice, and has pretty clean transitions

```css
.spoiler {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: help;
}
.spoiler::before {
    content: 'psst\02026'; /* &hellip; */
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    top: -2px;
    right: -2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    font-size: .9rem;
    color: #e6578c;
    background: #ffe5e5;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.7s ease, transform 0.3s ease; /* hide faster than reveal */
}
.spoiler:hover::before {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%)rotateX(80deg);
    transition: opacity 1.0s ease, transform 0.5s ease; /* slower reveal */
}
```

If you style the parent block with `opacity: 0` without hover, then you can't add any styles to illustrate what part of the page the user should be hovering over.

Instead, if we add a `::before` element that covers up the child content, then we can fade it out on hover and still provide a visual indication of where to go.

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

[image: Spoiler Demo]

```css
.spoiler {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: help;
}
.spoiler::before {
    content: 'psst\02026'; /* &hellip; */
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    top: -2px;
    right: -2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    font-size: .9rem;
    color: #e6578c;
    background: #ffe5e5;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.7s ease, transform 0.3s ease; /* hide faster than reveal */
}
.spoiler:hover::before {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%)rotateX(80deg);
    transition: opacity 1.0s ease, transform 0.5s ease; /* slower reveal */
}




/* demo styles */
blockquote {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<p>
  Inline Spoiler <span class="spoiler" > Word </span>
</p>

<p class="spoiler">
  Paragraph Text Block of a Spoiler
</p>

<blockquote class="spoiler">
  Block quote spoiler with super long text that wraps and wraps and wraps some more.
  
  Block quote spoiler with super long text that wraps and wraps and wraps some more.
  
  Block quote spoiler with super long text that wraps and wraps and wraps some more.
</blockquote>
```